# No connection with dockerized nginx gunicorn

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I've created simple example for dockerized django with nginx and gunicorn. But for some reason connection doesn't go through nginx.
Here is nginx.conf contents

```
worker_processes 1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 2;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    server {

        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.dj example.dj;

        location = /favicon.ico {
            alias /app/static_root/favicon.ico;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /app/static_root/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/app/example.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    hostname: web
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && gunicorn example.wsgi:application --workers 3 --bind unix:/app/example.sock"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
    expose:
      - "8000"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
      - ./config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - web
```

In /etc/hosts I have

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.dj example.dj
```

So when I run `docker-compose up` I expect to see django start page by http://example.dj url, but there is no connection. Can you guys help me with it?

Code available on the [github](https://github.com/MichaelPavlov/django-nginx-gunicorn-in-docker)

Comment: What does the output of `sudo netstat -ntlp` give you? What's the output of `sudo docker inspect <nginx container sha>` give you? Can you reach the service if you use IP directly?

Comment: `netstat -ntlp`:
https://dpaste.de/Bzu0

Comment: And `sudo docker inspect $(sudo docker ps -aq)`

https://dpaste.de/Nnwz

Comment: `curl http://127.0.0.1` gives `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: Actually it looks like nothing is listening for 8000 on the host machine. Are your containers running?

Comment: Yep, shouldn't it be 80 port exposed by nginx? I see. Here what I have with `sudo docker ps -a` https://dpaste.de/a9ya

Comment: Well, it seems like you have you nginx listening on port `80` inside the container, but are exposing port `8000` to the outside world and mapping the container's `80` to port `8000` on the host machine (based on your configs). The output you should be looking for is `sudo docker ps`, which shows you the running containers. `ps -a` shows you _all_ containers that have _ever_ run.

Comment: Then why port 8000 is not present in netstat?

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/port-80-for-docker-compose-yml-not-working/28496/4
Here is the same problem described and it's told that it might be firewall settings preventing port exposing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165747/discussion-between-ffledgling-and--).